# Delphi active X dll exception handling

Tags: delphi, dll, exception, activex

I have my Delphi executables accessing an ActiveX DLL which uses FireDAC.  All database-related functions are in the DLL.

When I make a remote database connection, if the connection is lost between the EXE and the database, accessing database-related functions from the DLL gives an error message:

> server closed connection unexpectedly

I want to know, can I set something like a global exception handler in the DLL which will be applicable to all EXEs that use it?

Comment: Exceptions should not be allowed to pass over the DLL boundary, and this is especially important in ActiveX.  The DLL needs to handle any exceptions internally, and return appropriate `HRESULT` error codes to the caller as needed.

Comment: You might want to read up on Delphi's [safecall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#safecall) calling convention.

Comment: Thanks..you are right. I get error at SafeCallErrorProc(ResultCode, ReturnAddress); in _CheckAutoResult in system.pas file..Need to handle this right?